# How to calculate when the network card opens a connection on Android

Tags: android, linux, networking

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to know when an app opens an internet connection and thus wakes up the network card.

So for example, I have the phone off and I decide to search http://www.cnn.com

In this case, lets imagine that no background data is going on from any app, so the connection is IDLE at the time I call the website. I want to know when the network card opened the connection to load the page.

I have found no APIs for this. Originally I was looking at the TelephonyManager which has different states of the network card (DORMANT, INOUT, NONE, etc), but I found my phone never goes to dormant, I believe this is due to fast dormancy. I have also been looking at linux filesystem files that might contain this information from the driver, but I have found none.

I read this nice article from ATT which explains about mobile networks

http://www.research.att.com/articles/featured_stories/2011_03/201102_Energy_efficient?fbid=xEv4RTIfUL9

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the answer is to use the SignalStrength class and the PhoneStateListener's onSignalStrengthsChanged in order to measure the radio signal. This helps detect when a connecdtion is made. Referenced from ATT's ARO app:

https://developer.att.com/application-resource-optimizer
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onSignalStrengthsChanged(android.telephony.SignalStrength)